# Reactnative razorpay is not working

Tags: react-native, razorpay

i am using razorpay in react native application (https://github.com/razorpay/react-native-razorpay)
Till yesterday i have install reactnative using npm. today i am not able to install from npm. and i followed the manual installtion steps. now i am not able to build the app using `react-native run-android`. Please help me to solve this.

error message:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
>   Configuration with name 'default' not found.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this and clean & build again..

```
In /android/settings.gradle file check following -

include ':react-native-razorpay'
project(':react-native-razorpay').projectDir = new 
File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-
razorpay/android/app/')
```

In android/app/build.gradle file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-razorpay')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"

}
```

MainApplication.java

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.razorpay.rn.RazorpayPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements 
ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new 
  ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new RazorpayPackage()
      );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
        return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
      return mReactNativeHost;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest version and (for android) after manual linking/installation, if your minSdkVersion in the top most build.gradle file is anywhere lower then 19, please turn it to 19, because that's the lowest version for which react-native-razorpay supports. then clean the gradle and build it again, i.e, go into android/ and `gradlew clean` and in the root project folder - `react-native run android`.